# I have an application, that uses the NDK, and it works perfect when I try to run it on some phones, but not on others

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik, renderscript, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My app works on a Nexus 5, Motorola Moto G4 and a tv box sex Minix Neo-X9.
But when I try running it on a LG G5 or a LeEco Le2 I get the following issue:

```
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): Process: com.vidyo.vidyomod, PID: 7264
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vidyo.vidyomod-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vidyo.vidyomod-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.vidyo.vidyomod-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libVidyoClientApp.so"
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.vidyo.VidyoClientLib.LmiAndroidAppJni.<clinit>(LmiAndroidAppJni.java:692)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1001)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:986)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:582)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5116)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1628)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
06-28 14:24:14.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

The code is the same, how can it work on a phone, and not work on another phone?
I mean, it runs the library perfect on some, and on the others not. And I tested, for example the LeEco is 6.00 and Nexus 5 which works is 6.0.1. So I don't think this is an Android OS issue

In my jniLibs folder I have this:
jniLibs->armeabi-v7a->libVidyoClientApp.so

Do I also need to have a folder like: jniLibs->arm64-v8a -> libVidyoClientApp.so or something like that?
Asking because of this line:

```
/data/app/com.vidyo.vidyomod-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libVidyoClientApp.so"
```

In my build.gradle I have this:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

Comment: and what is `libVidyoClientApp.so` ?

Comment: it's a native library file, that I have included inside my libs files.

Comment: I was on vacation, and before it worked, and I went through the commits my coleague did, one after another, and I figured the issue. check my response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 64-bit devices (most of modern phones and tablets), you should supply all libraries in **lib/arm64-v8a**, or none. If there are no 64-bit libs, the system will happily use 32-bit version from **lib/armeabi-v7a**. But if there is even one 64-bit lib (often coming from some 3<sup>rd</sup> party SDK), your app will crash with **UnsatisfiedLinkError**.

The easiest way to control this is to set `APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a` for **ndb-build**, [usually in **Application.mk** file](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#gc).

With Android Studio *(not your case, `jni.srcDirs = []` disables NDK integration)*, gradle overrides this. You need [**abiFilters** in **android.defaultConfig.ndk** block](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#specify-abi) or like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can compile all your libraries for 64 bit. For some heavy computational tasks, you can get a significant performance gain with little effort. In other cases, the gain is minimal, but porting C++ code to 64 bit may be challenging work. Also, this could inflate the size of your APK significantly. If you choose to supply both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app, it's recommended to [split the APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split).

Specifically for Render Script, the chances are that performance gain will not outweigh the hassle of dealing with multiple ABIs. Note that even if you set target API below 21, gradle will copy the 64-bit RenderScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was caused by a library that a coleague added:

```
compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
```

This library also needed in the android defaultConfig this:

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

And that was causing for some reason the library not to work on some phones

Comment: The trick is that on 64-bit devices, you should supply all libraries in **lib/arm64-v8a**, or none. If there are no 64-bit libs, the system will happily use 32-bit version from **lib/armeabi-v7a**. But if there is even one 64-bit lib (often coming from some 3<sup>rd</sup> party SDK), your app will crash with UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: @AlexCohn: should post that as an answer, since that's the real issue here

Comment: Yes, make an answer out of this, and I will accept it, cause it explains better what is going on in my app